# Create recursive query to add first and last in Chain of event

Tags: sql, sql-server, chain

I have a table containing 3 column

1. The contract number
2. The previous contract (if exist)
3. The following contract (if exist)

Table looking like this:

| Contract_numb | previous_Contract_numb | following_Contract_numb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DummyB | DummyA | DummyC |

I would like to restructure this table to recreate the chain of contracts, so putting the previous, current and following contract.
I'd like my result table to look like this:

| Contract_numb | previous_Contract_numb | following_Contract_numb | first | last |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DummyA | null | DummyB | DummyA | DummyC |
| DummyB | DummyA | DummyC | DummyA | DummyC |
| DummyC | DummyB | null | DummyA | DummyC |

Not sure how to achieve this, nor to call this, but first and last column can be dropped is too  complicated

Comment: Without "first-last" it's a UNION to collect all unique contact numbers and then double left join to your main table..

Comment: You could use a `VALUES` table construct to do this, but why all the repetition of data? You can find out the value of a next/previous row using `LEAD`/`LAG`. Seems like a better option would be to normalise your design.

Comment: @Larnu unfortunately the source table structure I'm working with doesn't allow that. Contract that are in one column, aren't in the others

Comment: @PM77-1 Thanks for you reply. Do you mean first column union second column union third column ?

Comment: Yes. If you use `UNION` (and not `UNION ALL`) it will get rid of duplicates.